# Как на jquery реализовать обесцвечивание и возврат цвета для блоков аккордеона bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css3

[image: Вот изначальная позиция]

при нажатии на  каждый блок - раскрывается скрытый блок - и все соседние цветные блоки сереют. при повторном нажатии цвет возвращается
если при раскрытом одном блоке нажать на другой - цвет должен перейти на него - как активный. а серый цвет всех остальных сохраняться
[image: вот раскрытый вид]

Answer (score 0):

В `css3` есть фильтр `grayscale` и оно делает то что вы хотите. Вот простой пример на `css3` и `jQuery`. При клике на `img` всех кроме текущей добавил определенный класс. И по этому классу добавил стили для `grayscale`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').on('click', function(event){
    $('img').addClass('grayscale');
    $(this).removeClass('grayscale');
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('body').on('click', function(){
    $('img').removeClass('grayscale');
  });
});
```

```css
img{
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
.grayscale { 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(grayscale.svg#greyscale); /* Firefox 4+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-uVpL-stvY3A/VOjA8Pblu3I/AAAAAAAACgw/KLIKxsNbo3Y/s1600/Google%2BDomains.png">
<img src="http://cdn1.qcs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/A-pat-on-the-back.jpg">
<img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/6d4904_3e7a9d31cb9c49a0af1c48f0f378e99f.jpg_256">
<img src="https://www.extension.umn.edu/food/small-farms/img/main.jpg">
```

Comment: мда. примерно так я и пробовал
но ваш код почему то блокирует раскрытие скрытого блока аккордеона при клике. правда я вписываю в область клика не img а класс div потому что картинка у меня в бакграунде. но наверно это не суть важно.  так вот переключение цвета  происходит а раскрытие блока нет

Comment: а понятно - это из за метода  event.stopPropagation();
если его убрать то блок раскрывается и сворачивается. но тогда цвет не возвращается. блоки остаются обесцвеченными

Comment: А можете кусок вашего кода показать?

Comment: да вот прям сам сайт
http://test.ufabike.ru/edrid

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.service-wrap').on('click', function(event){
    $('.service-wrap').addClass('grayscale');
    $(this).removeClass('grayscale');
   
  });
});

Comment: @ИгорьИгорев Сечас скажу как поправить

Comment: @ИгорьИгорев Посмотрите обновленный ответ, у меня сейчас нет такого глюка который вы сказали.

Comment: не так тоже не работает)
вот мне подскали как

 ` $('.service-wrap').on('click', function(event){
   if(!$(this).parents('a').hasClass('collapsed')) {
     $('.service-wrap').removeClass('grayscale');
   } else {
    $('.service-wrap').addClass('grayscale');
     $(this).removeClass('grayscale');
   }
   
  });`

Comment: @ИгорьИгорев на моем примере все это точно работает без глюков.